# pg_dump dumping files to ROOT

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-dump, postgresql-12

I run pg_dump last nite to backup some 111Gb database :
**`time pg_dump -j 5 -Fd -Z 1 db_profans -f /backup-nfs/`**

I monitor the size growth [image: here]

But, suddenly this morning, the database is down. I check the system directory. Root is full. *PS : I don't have any access to the server, we have different guys for managing it.*

What is going on ? Why all the backup files moving to root ? Or something else causing the root to fill up, maybe like WAL files created during backup or Log files piling up ? I do have replication for this database but it was a really minimal, just synchronizing 300 records daily. And I don't turn on any logging too..

How to delete all the backup files manually ?

Here is the [image: pic for the whole directory].

Updates:

I find out the cause of the problem is actually the archiving process is not written to an external disk. That folder "/Archive", which is supposedly hold the archived WALs, is **actually created inside the "root"** ! I did not know it because it was not like what I requested the other day before. Now as I delete the archived WALs, the server is up and running again.
So the cause is not from pg_dump process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like "the other guys" didn't set up the database very well. You don't have the database files in the root file system. Ideally, you create three file systems: one for the data files, one for `pg_wal` and one for the log files. That way, database data cannot fill up your root file system.

Since you perform `pg_dump` on the database machine (why??), your backup ends up in the same (and only) file system, and you happened to fill the disk. Don't do that!

Comment: I have WAL archiving folder outside the system and the `pg_wal` is hardly full, when I do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_ls_dir('pg_wal') WHERE pg_ls_dir ~ '^[0-9A-F]{24}';` it always stays at 100 for weeks (I didn't check prior to this error though..). Are you suggesting that I should create `pg_wal` directory on a mounted drive ? thanks

Comment: Oh, I see now that you ran the `pg_dump` on the database server machine. So it was you who filled up the only file system after all.

Comment: I run the `pg_dum` with `-f` option. That option is pointing out to some NFS outside. Prior to issuing `pg_dump`, I check the `/backup-nfs/` too. Seems working fine that time because the directory's size is increasing overtime .

Comment: I run this backup twice... The first one for a database with size only 8 Mb. The directory `backup-nfs` got filled up. Fine, no problem. The second one, for the 111Gb, fails. I use the exact same script. I also happened to test it on different machine too where the **backup location is on the same server but on different drive**. Of course this caused hdd to fill up and eventually I end up with **"can not create .s.PGSQL.5432"** error. I got out of this error easily ; just delete whatever in the backup folder and restart the server. @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe , your hunch is correct. It was not caused by `pg_dump`. Actually the `pg_wal` directory is full. I guess the archiving folder is full too so that the WALs can not be copied there.